# Powershell WebAdminstration New-Item: Length cannot be zero

Tags: powershell, iis, web-administration

I'm trying to use the following PowerShell script but get `Length cannot be zero` error:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$xml = [xml](Get-Content .\settings.xml)

$websites = $xml.Websites

foreach ($website in $websites.Website){    
   $dnsName = $website.DnsName

....

   #check if the site exists
   if (!(Test-Path "IIS:\Sites\$iisAppName" -pathType container))
   {
    $website = "IIS:\Sites\$($iisAppName)"

    $httpsBindingInformation = "*:443:"+$dnsName
    $bindings = @(@{protocol="net.tcp";bindingInformation="808:*"},@{protocol="https";bindingInformation=$httpsBindingInformation;sslFlags=1})

    $physicalPath = "$($directoryPathPrefix)$($iisAppName)"


    Write-Host "Creating website $($iisAppName)"
    #create the site
    $iisApp = New-Item -path $website -bindings $bindings -physicalPath $physicalPath
   }
}
```

Full error message is following:

```
New-Item : Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
At D:\CreateWebSites.ps1:51 char:13
+         $iisApp = New-Item -path $website -bindings $bindings -physicalPath $physicalP ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ArgumentOutOfRangeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

I cannot find out which parameter it is complaining about. `New-Item` has no parameter `Length`... Any hints?

Comment: You need to supply a `Name` for the new item, using the `-Name` parameter

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen in every example I find on Internet, there is no `Name` parameter. I tried to add `-Name` but then I get `Invalid site name`

Comment: Have you tried `New-Item -Path "IIS:\Sites\" -Name $iisAppName -physicalPath $physicalpath`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I get `Item type cannot be resolved from parent path \\Servername` if I try that

Comment: Hopefully you have already figured this out, but if not, have you tried stepping through your code? After assigning the $xml variable, do you have data there? Does $websites have data? Without your XML I'd guess the issue is here "$website in $websites.Website", I suspect it should be "$website in $websites".